# Creating articles programmatically: you have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, joomla

My code:

```
<?php

define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
  include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
  define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
  require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/libraries/joomla/factory.php';

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = array('title', 'fulltext', 'state', 'catid', 'created_by', 'access');

$values = array('test', 'test test test', 1, 9, 889, 1);

$query
  ->insert($db->quoteName('#__content'))
  ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
  ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Full error:

```
    Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: You have an error in your SQL
 syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'test test, 1 , 9, 889, 1)' at line 3 SQL = INSERT INTO `cxq09_content` (`title`, `fulltext`, `state`, `catid`, `created_by`, `access`) VALUES (test, test test test, 1, 9, 889, 1)
```

Joomla is installed on OpenServer.

What's wrong?

Comment: Additionally to quoting the values, as Strawberry (in his deleted comment) indicated: `FULLTEXT` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), you've got to quote this column. It seems that the quoteName() method doesn't work properly.

Comment: How to do that? I can't understand, I don't have much experience.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the values for the insert statement could be done with

```
$query
  ->insert($db->quoteName('#__content'))
  ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
  ->values(implode(',', $db->quote($values)));
```

if your Joomla version is new enough, see the [documentation to quote](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html#method_query):

> Quotes and optionally escapes a string to database requirements for
>   use in database queries.
>
> quote(mixed $text, boolean $escape = true) : string
>
> Note: Accepting an array of strings was added in 12.3

If your version don't accept an array of strings, you've got to quote every single array element.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This string resolved my problem: $values = array($db->quote('test'), $db->quote('test test test'), 1, 9, 889, 1); I should read documentation carefully.